# why doesnt Rails auto-generate foreign-key for associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

It's not hard to do this thick,also it hides all logic in model,so it also fits the philosophy of rails model.

So I am wondering if there is some good reasons of handtyping foreign-keys inside the migration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do it by hand. For example:

```
rails g model post user:references
```

creates migration adding `posts` table with `user_id` column and index on this column.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been around since Rails 1.  There were arguments for and against but at that time, the various db vendors differed substantially in their particular syntax for foreign key constraints and it was non trivial to implement across multiple db vendors.  At least that was my understanding at that time